# 128-bit integer type in GCC/Clang

Tags: c, integer, gcc, c89

When working on my projects, I often need a 128-bit integer type. For this purpose, I use the `__int128` compiler extension. Here is the implementation I am currently using:

```
/**
 * Support for 128-bit integers.
 */

#ifndef WIDEINT_WIDEINT_H_
#define WIDEINT_WIDEINT_H_

/* all GNU compilers */
#if defined(__GNUC__)

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpragmas"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"
typedef unsigned __int128 uint128_t;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

#define UINT128_C(n) ((uint128_t)n)
#define UINT128_MAX (~UINT128_C(0))

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpragmas"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"
typedef __int128 int128_t;
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

#define INT128_C(n) ((int128_t)n)
#define INT128_MAX ((int128_t)(UINT128_MAX >> 1))
#define INT128_MIN (-INT128_MAX - 1)

#else
#   error "Unsupported compiler"
#endif /* defined(__GNUC__) */

#endif /* WIDEINT_WIDEINT_H_ */
```

As you can see, the implementation is quite complex.

My questions are: Is it possible to get rid of all those `#pragmas`? (For example, no `#pragmas` are needed in OpenCL.) Will my implementation work in all cases? (Currently, I am using C89.) Any suggestions for improvement or constructive criticism are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

**Consider the future when `uint128_t` is standard and available**

You don't want your code to stomp on standard names, yet not require much code change.

Rather than `uint128_t`, `UINT128_C`, `UINT128_MAX` and the signed counterparts, use a different naming scheme like `my_...`.

You could then add code that *selectively* brings in your code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
// Only use the user version of uint128_t if not defined by the standard library.
#ifndef UINT128_MAX
  #define UINT128_MAX MY_UINT128_MAX 
  #define UINT128_C MY_UINT128_C 
  typedef my_uint128_t uint128_t;
  ...
  // or stuff all your code here without the `my_`.
  #include "users_int128.h"
#endif
```

**Future Ideas**

Certainly functions like `strtoint128()`, `sprint_int128()`, `int128_t round128(double)`, ... would be useful.

`PRId128` `SCNd128` and friends would be nice, but you  might not be able to supply them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's necessary to duplicate the the diagnostic pragma sequence.  Just ignore those diagnostics once at the beginning of the `#if` block and pop the previous state at the end.

That simplifies maintenance if you ever need to change the set of suppressed warnings.

Comment: What about `typedef unsigned uint128_t __attribute__ ((mode (TI)));`? It does not require the diagnostic `#pragma`s and I noticed that it generates the same assembly. I don't know about compatibility though.